# react native maps - white map issue on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to run my react native app with [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps). I am getting the white map with red border issue. I am sure the answer to that for me is the bottom comment [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/202). But when I implement it in code in xxx/android/app/src/main/java/com/xxx/MainApplication.java, I just get this error:

> error: package com.airbnb.android.react.maps does not exist

How do I get that package into the android build of my react-native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android/settings.gradle` has mappings from the projects/packages to their respective folder in `node_modules`.

In the react-native-maps docs it says this should be in android/settings.gradle:

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
```

However, observing my `node_modules/react-native-maps` folder, I saw that the path to the android folder was different than above, and had lib, then android. So I changed it to this (add "lib" before "android"):

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

Then cleaned and rebuilt the project in android studio, then it worked.